# What does this error mean?

Tags: google-fit, google-fit-sdk

Got the following in the logcat while using Google FIT api for android.

**No live data sources available for Sensory Registration Request{type Data Type{com.google.calories.expended[calories(f)]}**﻿

I have registered a listner and the following request to get calories expended by the user:

```
SensorRequest sensorRequest = new SensorRequest.Builder().setDataType(DataType.TYPE_CALORIES_EXPENDED)
                .setSamplingRate(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS).build();
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to fetch the data from the Google fit Cloud or from the sensors, if its cloud, go for HistoryAPI, and if its from sensors, may be the device doesn't have built in sensors to get calories burned, so try adding sensors via BLE with the help of BleAPI and then go for this call. 
You have to get a proper response i believe

Comment: how do i add sensors via BLE api?

Comment: Get to know what is BLE api first, I am sure you will get to know the answer to it on your own, anyway the steps of doing it is as follows.


1) with the help of  `Fitness.BleApi.startBleScan` find your device.
2) After you found the device, use `Fitness.BleApi.claimBleDevice` to claim that ble device.
3) Then use the `Fitness.SensorsApi.findDataSources` to find the datasource and start fetching the data
Note:
For 1, the device shouldn't be paired with other applications in the phone
For 3, Use the same datatype used in the request for step 1 as well as for step 3